# Web part using 3rd party permissions

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Is it possible to filter (i.e. hide) web parts from the `WebPartAdder` based on 3rd party user permissions?

We have built in user permissions in our application that defines which web parts a user has permissions to add to a page (permissions obtained using web services).  In previous versions of SharePoint, we created a custom web part picker that allowed our users to select and add web parts to a web part page based on those permissions.  In SP 2010 we'd like to use the SharePoint ribbon to expose these web parts but we haven't found a way to filter web parts based on these permission sets.

I've found virutally no usable documenation on MSDN describing the `WebPartAdder` control.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify permissions on webparts in the webpart gallery, but this doesn't remove them from the list of available webparts. The unauthorized user will get an access denied message when attempting to add them to a page.